# Trying to amemd CronJob's Via a PHP file

Tags: php, cron

I have a hosting platform that at midnight resets all cronjob added on there system to 15 from what ever they where set to. Our plan is to set up a script that run's every 8hrs and resets these back, so the process they manage are minimally interrupted. It is shared hosting, but hosting companies solution it an upgrade and a massive rise in costs.

The server specs are cPanel Version - 70.0 (build 69) | Apache Version - 2.4.39 |PHP Version - 7.2.18 |MySQL Version - 10.2.24-MariaDB-cll-lve |Architecture -  x86_64 | Operating System - linux

We have been suggested using a PHP class called Crontab to achieve this.

When we add a job, it appears in our cron job section of our server, but if we try to delete it from the server we get the following error 'Error New Lines are not permitted in crontab entries'. How ever we can remove the job via the Crontab class.

```
<?php
class Crontab {

    static private function stringToArray($jobs = '') {
        $array = explode("\r\n", trim($jobs)); // trim() gets rid of the last \r\n
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
            if ($item == '') {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }

    static private function arrayToString($jobs = array()) {
        $string = implode("\r\n", $jobs);
        return $string;
    }

    static public function getJobs() {
        $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
        return self::stringToArray($output);
    }

    static public function saveJobs($jobs = array()) {
        $output = shell_exec('echo "'.self::arrayToString($jobs).'" | crontab -');
        return $output; 
    }

    static public function doesJobExist($job = '') {
        $jobs = self::getJobs();
        if (in_array($job, $jobs)) {return true;} else {return false;}
    }

    static public function addJob($job = '') {
        if (self::doesJobExist($job)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $jobs = self::getJobs();
            $jobs[] = $job;
            return self::saveJobs($jobs);
        }
    }

    static public function removeJob($job = '') {
        if (self::doesJobExist($job)) {
            $jobs = self::getJobs();
            unset($jobs[array_search($job, $jobs)]);
            return self::saveJobs($jobs);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

//$output = shell_exec('crontab -l'); //Check server output
//echo nl2br($output); //Make it readable

Crontab::addJob('*/15 * * * * /opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php -q /home/path/bob.php process-log >/dev/null 2>&1');
Crontab::removeJob('*/15 * * * * /opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php -q /home/path/bob.php process-log >/dev/null 2>&1');

?>
```

The reason this is a concern is that for there to be a server error, then code inputting the cronjob must not be doing it right, I have hear of issue when running similar processes on windows servers, but the php file running the code is in the root of the linux server, so wasn't expecting to have issues.

IF someone could explain why this error is occurring and how to fix it, that would be greatly appreciated, let me know if you need any more info.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Don't use `\r\n` as the newline on Linux, it should just be `\n`.

Comment: Your code won't work if there are any `$` characters in the cron job. The `echo` command will expand the variables. It also won't work if the cron job contains double-quote characters.

Comment: You should use `escapeshellarg()` to solve those problems.

Comment: Surely that's a matter of raising a ticket with the hosting provider asking them to stop doing this?

Comment: Thank you Barmar, removing the \r, from the Crontab script, made it work, Matthew Daily, your suggestion was my first port of call, and they refused saying they didn't support it on shard platforms and said we should upgrade to a dedicated server costing a lot more, hence I was looking for another solution.